# Vagrant rsync-auto doesn't appear to be updating files on VM, on Mac

Tags: macos, vagrant, rsync

I've been using Vagrant on Windows for a while without issues with rsync-auto. Tried setting up my box on a MacBook Air, there are no errors on the command, but the folder does not seem to get updated with the new files. What's going on?

This is the setup I have in my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/<username>/<path>/<to>/<dir>", 
  "/var/www/html/<dir>", type: "rsync", rsync__exclude: ".git/",
  owner: "root", group: "root"
```

When I SSH into the VM, I see the files' modified date never changes.

Output of `vagrant rsync-auto`

```
$ vagrant rsync-auto
==> default: Doing an initial rsync...
==> default: Rsyncing folder: /Users/<username>/<path>/<to>/<dir>/ => /var/www/html/<dir>
==> default:   - Exclude: [".vagrant/", ".git/"]
==> default: Watching: /Users/<username>/<path>/<to>/<dir>
D, [2014-09-19T15:09:36.087365 #38613] DEBUG -- : Adapter: considering TCP ...
D, [2014-09-19T15:09:36.087457 #38613] DEBUG -- : Adapter: considering polling ...
D, [2014-09-19T15:09:36.087532 #38613] DEBUG -- : Adapter: considering optimized backend...
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: BTW, Vagrant RSYNC might change your permission levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neeeevermind. I figured it out.

I had the /var/www/html dir as only writable by root, so no changes were able to be made. Changed permissions to 777 (this is a VM so I don't really care) and it finally works. Dang permissions.

Comment: BTW, Vagrant RSYNC might change your permission levels.

Comment: @Coffee123, IDK. I changed my directory and it's doing fine now. couldn't sync file in `/var/www/html` :3

Comment: yours worked for some reason with `/app`, but after I restarted the box, it's not working anymore.  this one is working with the trigger, https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10002#issuecomment-419503397 

Answer (score 2):

I would rather say that the problem is that rsync watch does not work perfectly (it has sometimes HUGE lag) on OSX. There is a plugin that solves that https://github.com/smerrill/vagrant-gatling-rsync (look into Readme for details).

For me rsync to directory that is owned by root works without chmod, but as mentioned in docu for some folders you need to use *"--rsync-path='sudo rsync'"* argument. (https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/rsync.html)

Problem is described here https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3249 and they say that in 1.7 version it shall be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling rsync 2.6.9 via homebrew seems to have resolved this issue for me on MacOS Sierra.

```
brew install rsync
```

If you haven't already you may need to install Xcode 8 from the App Store first.